# Sub query on case statement impala

Tags: sql, impala

So I’m evaluating one table using a case statement but based on the result of the statement  I need to run 1 of 4 possible queries. I’m using Impala which doesnt allow for sub queries in the select statement.

Has anyone faced something similar?

Comment: I don't know Impala, but can it call a stored procedure or function?  I would investigate this first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Impala but maybe you can try below:

Run the 4 possible query first and store each values in a variable.

When you run your case statement then you can just use the variable values.